# Duplicity FilePrefixError When Including Absolute Path

Tags: ubuntu, backup, ubuntu-18.04, duplicity, duplicity-backup

I am running across an error happening when I decide to include other folders in my backup, and I am wondering how I can correct it.

My full `duplicity` command is

```
duplicity \
    --include='/home/MINE/Shareable**' \
    --include='/home/MINE/Pictures**' \
    --volsize 10 \
    --s3-multipart-chunk-size 5 \
    --s3-use-new-style \
    --asynchronous-upload \
    /home/MINE/webapps/webapp2 \
    s3://s3.amazonaws.com//MYBACKUP/MYMACHINE/apps/MINE/webapp2 \
    --full-if-older-than 30D
```

If I do not include the `--include` arguments, it runs fine, once they are included I receive a `FilePrefixError: /home/MINE/Shareable**`.

Yes, all these paths do exist.  To me, it seems as if duplicity is expecting the included paths to be relative to `/home/MINE/webapps/webapp2` rather than absolute paths.

How can I correct this?

**NOTE**

```
duplicity \
    --exclude='*' \
    --include='/home/MINE/Shareable**' \
    --include='/home/MINE/Pictures**' \
    --volsize 10 \
    --s3-multipart-chunk-size 5 \
    --s3-use-new-style \
    --asynchronous-upload \
    /home/MINE/webapps/webapp2 \
    s3://s3.amazonaws.com//MYBACKUP/MYMACHINE/apps/MINE/webapp2 \
    --full-if-older-than 30D
```

ends with a new message:

```
Last selection expression:
    Command-line include glob: /home/MINE/Pictures**
only specifies that files be included.  Because the default is to
include all files, the expression is redundant.  Exiting because this
probably isn't what you meant.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

I needed to switch around the ordering of the includes and excludes

```
duplicity \
    --include='/home/MINE/Shareable' \
    --include='/home/MINE/Pictures' \
    --exclude='**' \
    --volsize 10 \
    --s3-multipart-chunk-size 5 \
    --s3-use-new-style \
    --asynchronous-upload \
    /home/MINE/webapps/webapp2 \
    s3://s3.amazonaws.com//MYBACKUP/MYMACHINE/apps/MINE/webapp2 \
    --full-if-older-than 30D
```